# Modelform prepopulate foreign key

Tags: django, django-forms

Trying to set a foreign key per `modelform` instance i ve got the following models:

```
#models.py
Column(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()

Input(models.Model):
    column = ForeignKey(Column)
    text = models.CharField()
```

In `forms.py`, how do I set the `ForeignKey` for the Modelform instance?

```
#forms.py
class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, column_parameter):
        super(InputForm, self).__init__()
        self.fields['column'].value = calc_column(column_parameter) #this of course does not set the value


    class Meta():
        model = Input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not set it in init method. If you have to do it, then set it in save() method.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
    m = super(InputForm, self).save(commit=False)
    m.column = calc_column(column_parameter)
    if commit:
        m.save()
    return m
```

But in case you absolutely have to set this value, then i suggest you do it with initial data:

```
InputForm(initial = {'column':calc_column(column_parameter)})
```